# Many jquery ui dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

Im trying to show more dialogs depending of the size of my newsArray. Why isnt it working?, i just get 1 popup. I checked the array and its 7 items in it

```
                for(var i=0; i<newsArray.length; i++{

                            $("#dialog").dialog({

                                      resizable: true,
                                      width:"auto",
                                      modal: true,
                                      title:"test"    
                             });    
                 }
```

Comment: You missed closing parenthesis in for loop

Answer (score 1):

Use class instead of using Id for dialog initialisation. Moreover you cannot have multiple elements of same Id (if any)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/58/

Code:

```
<div class="checked" >Click to open dialog</div>
<div class="checked" >Click to open dialog</div>
<div class="checked" >Click to open dialog</div>
<div class="checked" >Click to open dialog</div>
<div class="checked" >Click to open dialog</div>
<div class="checked" >Click to open dialog</div>
<div class="checked" >Click to open dialog</div>
<div class="checked" >Click to open dialog</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    $(".checked").dialog({
        resizable: true,
        width: "auto",
        modal: true,
        title: "test"
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I think you missunderstod me, i have just 1 div. How can i automatically create more divs depending on how big the array is ?

Comment: I guess you cannot display multiple dialogs for same div content. Maybe you can try searching more on SO.

Comment: I could create elements in the for loop ?

Comment: As far as the content div remains different, yes you can.

Comment: Thanks ok or if i change to class, i could use the same class name then ?

Comment: Yes, use $(this) when you iterate or create a new element.